# Bootstrap Accordion - Toggle all nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a lot of nested bootstrap collapsible elements on a page. 
As example http://jsfiddle.net/JPgLT/7/

How can i set a link to toggle **all** elements only within the parent element?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#collapse-764" data-parent="#collapsible-" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">Headline 1</a>
            </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-764" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2 class="csc-firstHeader panel-title">
                            <a href="#collapse-765" data-parent="#collapsible-764" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">Headline 1.1</a>
                        </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-765" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Text 1.1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse-766" data-parent="#collapsible-764" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">Headline 1.2</a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-766" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Text 1.2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a special class `closeall` to the buttons, and then toggle the collapse state using jQuery..

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.panel-heading') // find the parent heading element
    .next('.panel-collapse')          // find the next collapse element
    .collapse('show')                 // make sure it's open
    .find('.panel-collapse')          // find inner collapse elements
    .collapse('toggle');              // toggle their state
});
```

Bootstrap 3 Demo: https://codeply.com/p/g0vquJl0Xn

**Related questions**
[bootstrap 3 collapse('hide') opens all collapsibles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966170/bootstrap-3-collapsehide-opens-all-collapsibles/22966401)

Comment: I followed this down to the collapse() call, is that something specific to Bootstrap? I've never seen it in jQuery before

Comment: Yes.. it's a Bootstrap component

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem a little differently, and I know you've already excepted an answer, but I thought I'd answer anyway as I'm pretty new to jQuery and would appreciate feedback

```
$el = $(".accordian-toggle").first();  //Use whatever selector you have to to select the parent element
$el.click(); //expand/toggle that element

//then use that elements href attribute as the selector to find all toggleable 'child' elements 
$($el.attr('href')).find(".accordion-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```