# bootstrap 3 collapse('hide') opens all collapsibles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve something rather simple, but can't get my head around it - Google hasn't been any help, and Bootstrap docs seem to be a bit confusing.

What I need:

- simple collapsible accordion, with all collapsibles in closed state on page load
- all collapsibles can be closed with one click on a button.

The problem:

- my solution only works when the user has opened/closed one or more collapsibles
- when I call `collapse('hide')`, **all collapsibles are opened**, unless they had already been opened manually before.

See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mx4x/).

My markup:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" id="collapseall"><span class="icon"></span>Collapse 'm all!</a>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#collapseall').click(function () {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
    return false;
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you have to only `hide` the open ones like this..

```
$('#collapseall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
```

Here is a working open/close all example: http://bootply.com/123636

Comment: That's indeed a reasonable solution, thanks. Though I'm still left with a feeling I don't fully grasp the logic behind the show/hide/toggle parameters of the bootstrap collapsible...

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, so I looked into bootstrap.js code, and figured out what's going on.

If you call collapse function without initializing collapse element as javascript, Bootstrap automatically initializes it first. Look at the **new Collapse** part. You can see why already opened element isn't a problem here.

```
// COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
// ==========================

function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.collapse')
      var options = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)

      if (!data && options.toggle && option == 'show') options.toggle = false
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
}

var old = $.fn.collapse

$.fn.collapse             = Plugin
```

This is collapse function:

```
var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element      = $(element)
    this.options       = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, options)
    this.$trigger      = $(this.options.trigger).filter('[href="#' + element.id + '"], [data-target="#' + element.id + '"]')
    this.transitioning = null

    if (this.options.parent) {
      this.$parent = this.getParent()
    } else {
      this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(this.$element, this.$trigger)
    }

    if (this.options.toggle) this.toggle()
}
```

The last line is point. If toggle option is true, **toggle** function is called.
It opens hidden collapsible element or closes shown collapsible element:

```
Collapse.prototype.toggle = function () {
    this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
}
```

The toggle option is default to true.

So, if you want to hide element as below,

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

you need to initialize element like this:

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({
  toggle: false
});
```

You can find more information in [Bootstrap collapse usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage).

Comment: $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide'); this solved my problem